# Formatting LINQ Query Result Set

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC application. This application executes a query via JQuery. The result set is returned as JSON from my ASP.NET MVC controller. Before I return the serialized result set, i need to trim it down to only the properties I need. To do this, I'm using a LINQ Query. That LINQ Query looks like the following:

```
private IEnumerable RefineResults(ResultList<Result> results)
{           
  // results has three properties: Summary, QueryDuration, and List
  var refined = results.Select(x => new
  {
    x.ID, x.FirstName, x.LastName
  });

  return refined;
}
```

When I execute this method, I've noticed that refined does not include the Summary and Duration properties from my original query. I'm want my result set to be structured like:

```
Summary
QueryDuration
Results
 - Result 1
 - Result 2
 - Result 3
 ...
```

At this time, when I execute RefineResults, I get the result list I would expect. However, I can't figure out how to put those entries in a property called "Results". I also don't know how to add the "Summary" and "QueryDuration" properties.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private object RefineResults(ResultList<Result> results)
{           
  // results has three properties: Summary, QueryDuration, and List
  var refined = results.Select(x => new
  {
    x.ID, x.FirstName, x.LastName
  });

  return new { Results = refined, Summary = results.Summary, QueryDuration = results.QueryDuration };
}
```

You will probably want to create a specific DTO class for the return value of this function.